# what is the difference between those uri's?

Tags: http, url

What is the **difference** between each of those urls ?

**When** will i use each ?

http://localhost/x

http://localhost:80/x

http://myComputerName/x

http://127.0.0.1/x

Comment: What were the results when you tested each of these URIs?

Comment: same... but i heard it has difference through firewall...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- http://localhost/x maps to 127.0.0.1 which is [loopback](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loopback). You can only use for
  local testing and can not give it to anyone on your network to visit
  the page.
- http://localhost:80/x is same as first because by default http works on port 80 and if you don't specify the port 80 is asumed
- http://myComputerName/x can be given to others on your network because then they can connect to IIS on your machine (by resolving your host name) on port 80 and request x page/folder
- http://127.0.0.1/x is same as first. It is IP address equivalent of localhost.

Comment: what is the advantage of using myComputerName ? they can also use the IP ...?

Comment: what about firewall point of view ?

Comment: Firewall has nothing to do with your question.